# Doxygen including methods twice doc files

Tags: objective-c, doxygen

I'm having this issue where doxygen is adding the method twice in the documentation file. Is there a setting that stops auto-generation of documentation for methods within the .m file.

For example in the documentation I'll see something like whats below where 
the first definition of + (Status *)registerUser is from the header XXXXXX.h file where the second is from XXXXXX.m.

Header documentation :

```
/**
    @brief   Test
    Yada Yada
    @return     <#(description)#>
*/
+ (Status *)registerUser;
```

Output:

```
+ (Status *) registerUser               

Test Yada Yada.

Returns:
    <#(description)#> 

+ (Status *) registerUser               

<#(brief description)#> <#(comprehensive description)#>

registerUser

Returns:
    <#(description)#> 

Definition at line 24 of file XXXXXX.m.
```

Comment: If it's any help to pinpoint this problem, it seems that it wants to inherit twice as well as says the documentation:
#import <XXXXX.h>
Inherits SuperClass, and SuperClass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved! I found out that doxygen was including my build directory and my .svn directories.

I added to EXCLUDE_PATTERNS

```
*/.svn/*
*/.build/*
```